# Is there a difference between these queries

Tags: django, django-models

I'm pretty sure these two queries are equivalent, but I could be wrong.

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

OK are these queries the same

```
 Sample.objects.exclude(~Q(file=''))
 Sample.objects.exclude(file__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a completely unnecessary use of the Q object. That is really only for one you want to add multiple conditions, especially if you are joining them with OR. And I can't see any reason to use `exclude` and `~` in the same condition.

However, the queries are not the same: the first excludes objects where the `file` attribute is not the empty string, whereas the second excludes objects where `file` is null; these are not necessarily the same.

Note that the second query could be expressed even more concisely:

```
Sample.objects.exclude(file=None)
```

Comment: So if I were looking for all samples that did have something set for the file, I should be .exclude(file=None)?